# Appearance of 2nd red woman

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In *Game Of Thrones*, a second Red Woman appears in a season (I think 7th), But we don't see her in the next season. Did she just appear in the episode to increase the curiosity between the fans?

To clarify, I would like to know:

1. Is she an important character (like Melisandre)?
2. Are there others like them?

Comment: What do you want to know about the 2nd red priestess (Kinvara, i believe). Please be more clear

Comment: What answer are you expecting? Who was she? Why did she appear? What happened to her? Please be more specific in your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Red Women in the show are simply priestesses in the faith of R'hllor. They are nothing special, except the one we follow through the show called "Melisandre"

This second one has no special role beyond that single episode in the series, so she is simply not mentioned anymore later.

You can read more about the cult and the red priests / priestesses in the [Game of Thronse Wiki Page](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Priest).

Here is an excerpt from that page:

> Red Priests and Red Priestesses are the clergy in the faith of R'hllor, the Lord of Light, and receive their name from the red clothing they wear. They appear to possess a multitude of ambiguous supernatural abilities, which are believed to be the gifts of the Lord Himself.

As seen on that page as well there are a LOT of mentions of red priests / priestesses in the series:

> **Known Red Priests**
>   - **Melisandre**, from Asshai. Called "the Red Woman", also a shadowbinder. Former adviser to Stannis Baratheon and Jon Snow.
>   - **Thoros**, from the Free City of Myr. Participated in the Siege of Pyke, fighting with a flaming sword. Became a member of the Brotherhood Without Banners before ultimately perishing during the Wight Hunt north of the Wall.
>   - High Priest of Myr.
>   - A Red Priestess in Volantis.
>   - A Red Priestess in Meereen.
>   - **Zanrush**, a Red Priest active in Meereen.
>   - **Kinvara**, High Priestess of the Red Temple of Volantis.

As you specifically ask about a Red Woman in one of the later seasons your question seems to be about **[Kinvara](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Kinvara)** (appearing in Season 6).

Thanx @TheLetalCarrot for pointing this out.

Comment: Kinvara is the specific Red Priest being spoken about, seems relevant to mention that.

Comment: Thanx for the information. Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are talking about [Kinvara](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Kinvara), her work was just to help Tyrion spreading the name of Daenerys. Which she did and had no other purpose to fullfill like many other characters.  Moreover she was not the second on-screen Red Priestesses.

The first one was Melisandre as you know but there are many other Red Priests and Red Priestesses shown or mentioned in the show. Like in season 3 Melisandre mentioned the order of High Priest given to  Thoros, which he failed to do.

Also in S05E03, [Unnamed Red priestess](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Priestess_(High_Sparrow)) appeared preaching about Daenerys being the prophesied savior, which Tyrion noticed and even mock. This might have inspired Tyrion to use Kinvara for religious influence.

And even after that another [unnamed Red Priestess](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Priestess_(No_One)) appeared which supposedly doing the task what Tyrion asked Kinvara to do.

Also, you might be forgetting about [Zanrush](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Zanrush) and Thoros.

Answer (score 1):

Kinerva is one shot character, but one who offers the series a few important things:

1. She helps to prove that Melisandre isn't a complete liar by showing viewers another R'hlllor follower in the form of another Red Priestess who dresses nearly identical.
2. This in turn helps to world build and plays into the "bigger picture" narrative, as this particular religion or belief in R'hllor: The Lord of Light (and/or the reincarnation of Azor Ahai) is seen as the anti-thesis to The Night King (TV Show)/The Great Other(Novels) and is a strong motivator of what these sorts of characters do and/or affect the lives of other characters.
3. She also juxtaposes Melisandre in some respect, as Melisandra is often presented as the character who is using/manipulating others to accomplish her goals or beliefs, but in this case it at first comes off as if Tyrion using Kinerva to politically motivate the people of Mereene to spread Daenerys' name, but Kinerva acts as though this was always her designation; that Dany may be Azor Ahai/The Last Hero, but ironically this puts her at odds with Melisandre's belief in Stanis and/or Jon Snow and allows viewers to question this religion and/or how metaphysics works in GOT/ASOIAF.